# DB Connection Unavailable Lambda with Cloud Watch Event Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm having issues connecting to mongodb when I am using a cloud watch event rule to trigger lambdas to keep them warm and also the same issue when I tried using serverless-plugin-warmup. Anyone have and ideas as to why this would be happening? Also I whitelist IP's for my database and use an Elastic IP for my lambda functions. Could the cloud watch event rules be causing the lambdas to use a different IP?

`{"error":{"name":"MongoError","message":"no connection available"}}`

I wrap my functions with the following to make sure the database is connected before running code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let cachedDB = null;

module.exports = fn => (...args) => {
  const [, context] = args;

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  if (cachedDB && cachedDB.readyState != 0 && cachedDB.readyState != 3) {
    fn(...args);
  } else {
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);

    mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
      console.log('Connection Error');
      console.log(err);
    });

    mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
      cachedDB = mongoose.connection;
      fn(...args);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: This part doesn't make sense: "and use an Elastic IP for my lambda functions" you can't assign elastic IPs to Lambda functions. Do you mean you assigned an elastic IP to the MongoDB server? What you should be doing is placing the Lambda function in the same VPC as the MongoDB server, and addressing the server using the private IP, not the public or elastic IP.

Comment: @MarkB I'm using Mongo Atlas (database as a service) which I am whitelisting an IP that I created via Elastic IP. My lamba functions are within a VPN. I set up an internet gateway, subnets, nat gateway, and elastic ip so that when my lambdas connect to mongo atlas there is one static ip they are using.

Comment: That's a lot of info that should have been in the original question. So the Lambda functions are in a VPC, in private subnets with a route to a NAT Gateway, and you have an Elastic IP assigned to the NAT gateway? I would first try connecting to MongoDB from an EC2 instance in one of those same private subnets to make sure the connection from VPC->NAT->Mongo is working.

Comment: @MarkB mongo definitely works, but when I set up the cloud watch event rules to trigger the lambdas every 5 minutes I will get the mongo error.

Comment: I'm sure "mongo definitely works". I'm trying to help you debug your VPC network configuration, since that's the most likely area that could be causing connectivity issues between Lambda and the Mongo Atlas service.

Comment: @realseanp Does it work properly when invoked in a way other than a Cloudwatch Event?

Comment: @dashmug yes it works when invoked via api gateway

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle warmup events as a special case in your handler. Basically, your handler should return right away when it is invoked via a warmup event.

In the example given in `serverless-warmup-plugin`, you can do it this way,

```
module.exports.lambdaToWarm = function(event, context, callback) {
  // Immediate response for WarmUP plugin
  if (event.source === 'serverless-plugin-warmup') {
    console.log('WarmUP - Lambda is warm!')
    return callback(null, 'Lambda is warm!')
  }

  // add lambda logic after
}
```

Notice that there is an *if* statement at the beginning to check if it's a warmup event. If it is, return successfully right away.

This check should be at the beginning so that it doesn't have to connect to MongoDB at all.

Comment: I'd prefer to use CloudWatch event rules over the serverless warmup plugin. I am able to pass my own custom event data from the cloudwatch event rule. Early return is not the issue here. I was already doing that. However you have made me realize that maybe i can return in my higher order function.

Comment: I agree with you and use a custom event data. It was just easier to illustrate it using the plugin.